# JS error from jquery upgrading primefaces from 5.2 to 5.3

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces Dialog Framework in my webapps. Dialogs are showned by clicking on p:commandButton with the code below :

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{myBean.myDialogOpen}">
    <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{myBean.myDialogClosed}" update="@form" />
</p:commandButton>
```

It works fine with Primefaces 5.2, but if I switch to 5.3, dialogs are not showing up anymore and the whole page is frozen after I click the button. When I debug the code, I can see that DefaultRequestContext.openDialog(...) is executed correctly but in firebug's JS console I get this error from jquery.js (ligne 1, col. 231) :

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list
```

I have no clue where to start to find out what is going wrong. Did anybody meet that issue already ? Any advices please ?

Edit for Mahendran, the code of myDialogOpen

```
public void myDialogOpen() {
    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("draggable", false);
    options.put("resizable", false);
    options.put("dynamic", true);
    options.put("contentHeight", "'100%'");
    options.put("contentWidth", "'100%'");
    options.put("height", "210");
    options.put("width", "280");
    Map<String, List<String>> params = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    if (patientDescription.getLocation() != null) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(patientDescription.getLocation().getId().toString());
        params.put("id", list);
    }
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog(
            "/pages/dialogs/origin.xhtml", options,
            params.size() > 0 ? params : null);
}
```

Comment: show myDialogOpen method in MyBean

Comment: check if RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog(
            "/pages/dialogs/origin.xhtml"); produces js errors. I am guessing your params has some issue. Sys out patientDescription.getLocation().getId().toString() to see if any escaping is required. Open a bug in https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces

Comment: JS error is not produced by openDialog() method, and it occurs even when params Map is empty. The JS error is produced much longer in the stacktrace by tomcat's org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher doForward(...) method.